# Xamarin Forms buttons have border on API 23 devices

Tags: android, button, xamarin.forms, border

I have the following global style that I hoped would turn off the button borders on Android:

```
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
```

On Android API 19, everything looks fine.  On API 23 device, I get borders around the buttons:

[image: Screen shot showing borders]

Any idea how to get rid of these?

Comment: I have the same issue, I had to use a Label as a button. or you can always use a custom renderer.

Comment: Yeah I just should not have to write that kind of stuff in the modern world lol :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I had no choice but to change the buttons to StackLayouts and attach a gesture recognizer to the StackLayout similar to the following:

```
<StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="btnMore_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
```

While it sucks - it basically means anyone who wants to use the Xamarin Forms button controls with a transparent background - STOP - it will not work correctly on the newer Android platforms.  Just save yourself the trouble and use a simpler control and attached a gesture recognizer to it.